# How come I'm getting a This File or Directory doesn't exist? I have made the folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, directory, discord.js

So I made this code to pull from this Directory : Commands, as you can see in the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wc9X.png)
but I get a error message saying that file does not exist. The file is in the same folder as the javascript but it seems like the javascript is not able to get to the folder. Why is this happening and how can I fix it.

here is code

```
    const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const Discord = require('discord.js');
    const client = new Discord.Client();
    client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);

    client.once('ready', () => {
      console.log('Ready!');

     });

      client.login(token);

         client.on ('message', message => {
         if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

          const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
                const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
               if (!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try {
      client.commands.get(command).execute(message, args);
       } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
           }

          });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your workplace is "COMMANDS" and your bot.js isn't there.

You need to place your bot.js in the COMMANDS directory and there make another folder called "commands" and there you place your commands